# Not able to set the JavaScript JSON object value into Form

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-mvc

My JSP:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myForm" action="/action">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkboxValue" />
  <input type="hidden" name="jsonObject" id="jsonObj" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function getjson()"/>
</form:form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getjson(){
  var json = [];
  var checkedBoxes = $('input[name="checkedList"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  var checkedBoxes1 = $('input[name="checkedList1"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  json.push({"id":checkedBoxes});
  json.push({"Flap":checkedBoxes1});
  document.getElementById("jsonObj").value = json;
}
```

I have a `MyForm.Java`:

```
private String checkboxValue;

private jsonObject jsonObject;


//getters and setters
```

Here the value of `checkboxValue` is saving in variable `checkboxValue` but the `jsonObject` is not binding with the variable. I don't know why. Need some serious help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jsp` should be like this

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myForm" action="/action" id="Submitform">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkboxValue" />
  <input type="hidden" name="jsonObject" id="jsonObj" value=""/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getjson()"/>
</form:form>
```

And Your `javascript` should change to this

```
function getjson(){
  var json = [];
  var checkedBoxes = $('input[name="checkedList"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  var checkedBoxes1 = $('input[name="checkedList1"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  json.push({"id":checkedBoxes});
  json.push({"Flap":checkedBoxes1});
  document.getElementById("jsonObj").value = json;
  document.getElementById("Submitform").submit();
}
```